# use facebook sdk on localhost. Must I use https?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I’m trying to write a web app where the users can log in with their Facebook account. The app should let the user log in through Facebook with a button and once he has logged in he’s redirected to my app and then he will
Receive an email, user ID and other information. To upload the SDK of Facebook I have used jQuery like it’s described in the official documentation and I have written this few code lines to star testing everything

```
$(document).ready( function($scope) {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
        console.log("Facebook loaded; initializing sdk.");
        FB.init({
            appId            : '/*app-id*',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v3.3'
        });
    });

    $('.fblogin').click(function() {
        checkLoginState();
    });

    // callServer(/*'pyExecute',*/false);

});

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    });
}
```

but when I do it I received this error “The method FB.api can no longer be called from http pages” but I’m able to see my name in the console. However if I add FB.checkLoginStatu I receive this error “The method FB.getLoginStatus can no longer be called from http pages”. I don’t understand if I need to test everything in https, if there’s some method that works in http or if I need to do my local host in https. I already tried to see in stackoverflow and follow some guides, but I continue to receive the same errors

Comment: In my knowledge to use such sdk you need https severs, since localhost dont provide https, its better to use `ngrok`. Please refer the url `https://ngrok.com/`

Comment: @AkhilAravind localhost does "provide https". You just need a certificate (and a self-signed one would suffice)

Comment: I think `localhost` should still be exempt from that restriction - but only if your app is currently in dev mode, if you have set it live already, then HTTPS is a must no matter what.

Comment: Yes, here it is, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/: _“You will still be able to use HTTP with “localhost” addresses, but only while your app is still in development mode.”_ That article is a bit over a year old, but I am not aware of any further restrictions since then.

Comment: @Phillip i have read also about this method and i have follow the guide on "let's encript" but nothing. Maybe I made some mistake. I have used this command: openssl req -x509 -out localhost.......

Comment: @misorude yes, i have already read that article, but i don't understand why fb.login and fb.api works, but fb.checkstatuslogin not

Comment: Is your app in dev mode, or not? // Don’t bother with Let’s Encrypt, you can not use that for localhost. As was mentioned, ngrok is really one of the simplest alternatives that saves you all the hassle of getting your localhost set up to use HTTPS, by providing a simple “tunnel” to your machine.

Comment: @misorude Sorry. Yes, it's in dev mode. Ok, now i'll try ngrok. Thanks

Comment: Plain http isn't allowed, even on localhost, regardless of dev mode or enforce HTTPS settings (or any setting anywhere). You can verify this by reading the FB login SDK code -- all it does is compare the protocol against the literal string "https" before bailing.

Comment: @dpk At the end, I've solved in this way: 
- using ngrok to create an https tunnel
- using my application on facebook such as test
- setting the domain app such as ********.ngrok.io
- setting in fb login>setting>URI Oauth ********.ngrok.io